# WPF DataGrid, showing errors in row header with ToolTip

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, tooltip

Default style for DataGridRow is as following:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridRow}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static 
                                      SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Foreground="Red" Text="!" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
      ... 
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I want is to add ToolTip to TextBlock which displays "!" in the row header, and it will get an error message from DataGridRow.Item.Error property (My entity object implements IDataErrorInfo). So I did the following:

```
<TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Foreground="Red" Text="!"
           ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={
                             RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                             AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                             Path=Item.Error}"/>
```

So far so good. Now, Error property returns multi-line string, so I want to use TextBlock for ToolTip:

```
<TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Foreground="Red" Text="!">
  <TextBlock.ToolTip >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={
                              RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                              AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                              Path=Item.Error}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
  </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

But the above won't display error message; the problem seems to be ToolTip is not part of parent element's visual tree. I've read about PlacementTarget etc., but still couldn't get the job done. Can someone show me proper way of doing the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is to bind to relative source of the given element's property (PlacementTarget), not the element itself. But RelativeSource markup extension describes the location of the binding source relative to the given element. So, what I did was to
set PlacementTarget to the ancestor of original tooltip target:

```
<Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <TextBlock Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 TextAlignment="Center"
                 Foreground="Red" Text="!"
                 ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={
                              RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                              AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip >
          <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, 
                   RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item.Error}"/>
          </ToolTip>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
      </TextBlock>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Now it works as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ancestor level in that textblock as like below

```
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={
                          RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                          AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow},AncestorLevel=1},
                          Path=Item.Error}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```